# Loop or iterate through columns in a DataFrame to replace null values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that is 762106 rows x 79 columns. There are 14 'sets' of three columns with each column indicating a different level of 'intensity' for a given feature, and NaN where there is a value in another column. They are already encoded and I want to condense them into a single column so that instead of 42 of these columns I have 14.

A subset can be recreated like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    
df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 2, np.nan, 1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 3],
                    [1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2, np.nan, 1, np.nan, np.nan],
                    [np.nan, np.nan, 3, 1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2, np.nan]],
                   columns=['a','aa','aaa','b','bb','bbb','c','cc','ccc'])
```

Output:

```
    a       aa      aaa     b       bb      bbb     c       cc      ccc
0   NaN     2.0     NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     3.0
1   1.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     2.0     NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN
2   NaN     NaN     3.0     1.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     2.0     NaN
```

I want them to look like this:

```
    a   b   c
0   2   1   3
1   1   2   1
2   3   1   2
```

My current solution is to take values from aa, aaa, etc using `.fillna()` and then use `.drop()` to drop the superfluous columns:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].fillna(df['aa']).fillna(df['aaa'])
df = df.drop(['aa','aaa'],axis = 1)
    
df['b'] = df['b'].fillna(df['bb']).fillna(df['bbb'])
df = df.drop(['bb','bbb'],axis = 1)
```

And this works, but I want to know if there is a more elegant way to accomplish this without copy pasting this code block 14 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `axis = 1` ("columns"):

```
df.groupby(lambda x: x[0], axis = 1).sum()
     a    b    c
0  2.0  1.0  3.0
1  1.0  2.0  1.0
2  3.0  1.0  2.0
```

If groupby is used with a function, it's called on each value of the object's index, in this case, the columns names.

Since you can group by any function, it can be a really flexible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can grouping by first letter in columns names with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df = df.groupby(df.columns.str[0], axis=1).first()
print (df)
     a    b    c
0  2.0  1.0  3.0
1  1.0  2.0  1.0
2  3.0  1.0  2.0
```